# convert boolean value to SortOrder enum value

Tags: .net, ado.net, enums, ado

i am reading boolean value (value would either `1` or `0`) using data reader in `ADO.NET` from a table and want to type cast value to `SortOrder` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscy145f.aspx).

I am getting error if i use `Enum.TryParse` method to convert value. Any alternative solution.

```
SortOrder order;
Enum.TryParse<SortOrder>(bool value);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's boolean, you are over thinking the problem.

```
SortOrder order = (value) ? SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.None;
```

... or whatever your condition needs to be.